# Automated CRUD in Java using Swing JTable

Tags: database, swing, jtable, javafx, javafx-8

I used [this](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2010/02/display-any-resultset-in-jtable.html) code for displaying a database table in a JTable but when I change a value it is not saved to database. I'm using IntelliJIdea. I want to know if there is a general package to implement this kind of binding with database table? I've seen that netbeans can do sth similar. But I'd like to have an IDE independent method for this problem.

By the way, if Swing can't do it, is there a component in JavaFX which would be able to do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for javaFX  there is a library with write back support [DataFX2.0](http://www.javafxdata.org/)

Sample Examples can be found  [here](https://bitbucket.org/datafx/datafx/overview)

If you need any further help on datafx then you can post in datafx google groups [Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/datafx-dev)